# Align Image and text in a table row

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment, vertical-alignment

I have a table likes this:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign="middle;"><img src="icon.jpg" style="vertical-align: middle;" />title</td>
<td valign="middle;">detail</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want the image, title and detail to be aligned in a row, so I apply valign to the 3 elements. But it doesn't work well as image can only align with title but image+title cannot align with detail. Please help.

Comment: put the title in a seperate td

Comment: @Jawad just based on the image `src` being `icon.jpg`, I would guess that that approach probably doesn't make sense

Comment: @ultranaut: That's a good guess.

Comment: Adding one more td for the image is a good suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

remove `;` from the value of `valign` attribute